# Why does Samba always time-out whilst copying a large file off a network share?

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba, clipboard, timeout

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 (natty), kernel 2.6.38-8-generic, GNOME 2.32.1.

**EDIT:** As of 3 April 2012 I'm now on kernel 2.6.38-13-generic (still same Ubuntu and GNOME). The problem still persists.

I have a Synology DiskStation DS207 NAS connected to my home network. Both of these devices are connected to the network via wired gigabit ethernet.

I access the NAS via Samba on the Ubuntu box.

My problem is that every time I try to copy a large file from one of the NAS's Samba shares to the Desktop on the Ubuntu box using Nautilus, the operation times-out and fails about a third of the way through the copy (roughly about 3 mins into the operation).

I have retried the copy 3 times and the same thing has happened every time.

However, I also have a Windows 7 installation on a different drive in the same PC as the Ubuntu install, and if I boot into Windows 7 and try to copy the file using that OS instead then it works perfectly. This proves (to me at least) that the file and the network connection and hardware are actually all fine.

So does anyone have any ideas about what might be going wrong when trying to copy the file in Ubuntu? Is there simply a "samba keep-alive" setting or similar that I need to set somewhere?

By the way, here's a screenshot of the error I get:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: I have the same problem too. The server and the desktop are Ubuntu 11.04. The copying stops after appx. 200 Mbytes. The server still alive, because windows clients can reach it and use the shares more, but the Ubuntu desktop can't ping the server (no route to host or unreachable messages when I try to ping). So I think the problem on the smbclient side. Other symptom, I often get a dbus error message, "unable to mount <sharename>", but the share is mounted and usable (until start to copy a bigger file).

Comment: @BlueXrider, I have not yet found a solution, although I also do not recall running into the problem recently (probably more due to not having had to copy any large files lately). I will re-test soon, and re-post if the problem still happens. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @BlueXrider, I've just re-tested this and sadly it does still happen. I am still on Ubuntu 11.04 (I like my Classic Gnome too much) but the system is otherwise kept up-to-date.

I'd therefore appreciate it if this could be un-flagged for closure, if that's at all possible.

Comment: done, please edit your question and keep us posted it will then stay open until another round of reviews, regards

Answer (score 1):

My problem solved. I checked the server hardware and recognized, two of fans are blocked because of dirt (motherboard and video card). After cleaning and oiling bearings of the fans the server is working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the reply. However, I'm a little dubious as to whether my problem is caused by the same thing - if dust and overheating were the cause, then I'd expect it to fail no matter what operating system was being used... But unfortunately this is not the case for me.